# Telerik RadChart Binding With Multiple Series

Tags: telerik, radchart

I would like bind a rad chart with multiple serieses with different datasets (dtDev,dtProd, dtQA), Could tell me how to the coding?

Just take blind examples as we have three dates dtDev,dtProd, dtQA.

Please healp, Thank You in Advance!

```
monthlyradchartcontrole.Clear()
Dim dtDev as dataset = nothing
dtDev = obj.datareturn(parameters)

monthlyradchartcontrole.DataSource = dtDev

monthlyradchartcontrole.DataBind()

monthlyradchartcontrole.Series(0).DataXColumn = "ScheduledStartDate"
monthlyradchartcontrole.Series(0).DataYColumn = "ChamberUtilization"

monthlyradchartcontrole.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = monthlyXaxislableName
monthlyradchartcontrole.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.Visible = True
                monthlyradchartcontrole.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Appearance.TextProperties.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red
monthlyradchartcontrole.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Appearance.Position.Auto = True

monthlyradchartcontrole.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.Visible = True
monthlyradchartcontrole.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = monthlyYaxislableName
                monthlyradchartcontrole.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Appearance.TextProperties.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red
monthlyradchartcontrole.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Appearance.Position.Auto = True

monthlyradchartcontrole.Legend.Visible = False
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is putting the columns from T1 and T2 next to each other:

```
T1.a, T1.b, T2.a, T2.b
```

which I don't think is what you want. You probably want:

```
a, b
```

So you should use a union:

```
select T1.a, T1.b 
  from T1
union select T1.a, T1.b 
  from T2
  into T3
```

If you do want more than one table's columns inserted into another table try this:

```
select T1.a, T2.b
  from T1 inner join T2 on T1.ClientID = T2.ClientID
  into T3
```